# Difference between using OpenGL and 3D modelling software

Tags: java, opengl, blender

What is the difference between creating graphics with OpenGL and a 3D modelling software like Blender or Maya. Is the difference same as that between using machine language and a high level language to write code? Is it lengthier to model using OpenGL than with Blender or Maya?

Comment: OpenGL is not software, it is something you use to ***build*** software. Blender and Maya will typically sit on top of OpenGL for hardware accelerated rendering because they are actual pieces of software. So this question does not make a whole lot of sense, that is like asking what the difference between an apple and a carbon atom is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL provides an API which allows you to interact directly with your graphics card. Software like Blender and Maya add layers of abstraction on top of this, making them easier and more intuitive to use. The approaches are also different: whereas using OpenGL involves writing function calls in order to do things like render polygons to the screen, software like Maya and Blender are instead interacted with through a GUI, where you create the vertices through point and click.

Note that OpenGL by itself is not good at actually creating models. Instead, it's usually used for taking data representing models created in another program (such as Maya or Blender) and rendering these to the screen. Maya and Blender still rely on OpenGL for actually rendering stuff on screen (or DirectX could also be used), as do all programs which require drawing stuff on screen.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a programmatic interface that you use to instruct a graphics card to draw some graphics.

Blender and Maya are programs that give you an *user interface* to design various types of graphics.

Once you have something modelled in Blender, you can use OpenGL to render it. Indeed, tools like Blender can use OpenGL (or another API such as Direct3D) internally to display everything you see during work.